# Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method. Error on LINQ Query

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am running a linq query against CRM 2011 and I keep getting this error:

Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

My code looks like this:

```
        try
        {

            string rsmName = "Bob Harrison";
            var linqQuery = (from r in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                             join c in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference) r["accountid"]).Id equals c["accountid"] into opp
                             from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where ((EntityReference)r["ownerid"]).Name.Equals(rsmName)
                             select new
                                        {
                                            AccountId = !r.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : r["accountid"],
                                            Account = !o.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : o["name"]
                                        });

            ddlCustomer.DataSource = linqQuery;
            ddlCustomer.DataValueField = "AccountId";
            ddlCustomer.DataTextField = "Account";
            ddlCustomer.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks CRM Linq provider has a limited capabilities and the query is too complex. Try to use [FetchXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928434.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the Linq provider, but an issue with `EntityReference`s. There's unforunately no documentation on it, but my best guess is that since there's no constructor for `EntityReference` that takes a name, it is ordinarily null unless it's otherwise populated.

But anyway, this can still be done via [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) the same way it would be done via [fetchxml](/questions/tagged/fetchxml) - by querying the `SystemUser` table. See below (you'll have to translate to late-binding).

```cs
var linqQuery = from r in gServiceContext.OpportunitySet
                join c in gServiceContext.AccountSet on r.AccountId.Id equals c.AccountId into opp
                from o in opp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where o.OwnerId.Id == gServiceContext.SystemUserSet.Single(y => y.FullName.Equals(rsmName)).SystemUserId
                select new
                {
                    AccountId = !r.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : r["accountid"],
                    Account = !o.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : o["name"]
                };
```